# APK written in android 2.2 to run an APK written in 2.3?

Tags: android

I would like to write a general application which will use other applications as services (a.k.a plugins). I need to write that application on API 8 (2.2) and one of the plugins needs API 10+ (2.3.3). Can it be done? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make closure,

Yes, it can be done, I did it and it worked.